# Technology transformation from Flex 4 to HTML 5

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, html, frameworks

The company I am working for is planning for a technology transformation. We are currently using Flex 4.5 for our front-end development and php for the database interaction with MySQL as our database. We are using LCCS for our push requirements. As we know that Adobe is planning to stop support for LCCS late this year and hence it will be a problem for us in the near future. Definitely HTML/js will be our best choice and HTML5 is seen as future.

When searched on the net for this transformation, there seem to be numerous amount of framework for javascript. Here are few elements we be interested in:

1. MVC framework which supports binding and rich event based architecture
2. Hot code pushes w/ ability for continuous integration and deployment
3. Cross browser compatibility
4. Preferrably single code base for all Form factors (mobile and tablets)
5. Scalable
6. Good community support
7. Rich UI framework
8. Push mechanism (like LCCS)

Any pointers / experiences will be of a great help!

Thanks,

Anji

Comment: You should take this to programmers.stackexchange.com, because it is very broad and does not address a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ExtJs which would be the closest thing that looks like Flex in javascript , or SproutCore. Now dont expect js developpement to be as smooth as flex developpement ,no IDE , no real GUI builder ( though extJs has one ) , and you'll have to re-invent a lot of things before actually starting to build something. extJs is not free , but it should not be a problem since you might have paid for Flex. oh , and no AMF of course between javascript and php , good luck.

Comment: I second this. While you will probably get 6,7 on your list quickly - 3 will be a never ending nightmare. Just checking out what "HTML5 Wizardry" is out there now, worked on FF, but not Chrome. I stopped all bothering with it right then and there. No need to live the "web developer" days of my early 20's before jumping ship on to Flash 4/5.